# hyper v replication destination on

Tags: replication, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I want to test out 2012R2's Hyper V replication feature but I don't want to have to fork out for a new dedicated Hyper V host until I'm sure that the built in replication is fit for my needs. We have one existing 2012R2 hyper V host that is live but underutilised, can I enable replication on it and use it as a replica server as well as a live host?

Comment: It can't replicate to itself. You need two Hyper-V hosts to use Hyper-V Replica. You can install another server long enough to test Hyper-V Replica. I believe the Activation grace period is 60 days so that should give you plenty of time to test.

Comment: I understand that it can't replicate to itself, but I'd like to test replication from HV live server 1 > hyper v live server 2.  Can I enable replication on live server 2 and still run my live VMs as well?

Comment: Yes. Hyper-V Replica doesn't prevent or prohibit you from running other, non-replicated virtual machines. Once Hyper-V replica is configured in Hyper-V, the replication of virtual machines is specific to the virtual machines that you configure to be replicated. All other virtual machines run completely independent of Hyper-V Replica.